# Count the number of occurrences of each character in a string, ignoring CRs

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm scanning through all characters in a textbox. Then the program counts how many of each character is in the textbox. Here's the code which adds all characters to a list:

```
For each c as char in TxtBox
    list.add(c)
Next
```

Everything's working fine, except this will also add returns to the list, which I don't want. I thought I could write like this:

```
If c <> chr(10) Then
    list.add(c)
End If
```

...but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: You would also need to exclude chr(13).   10 = new line, 13 = carriage return.

Comment: Maybe the `Char.IsLetter(Char)` method helps if you just want to count letters you can do var countedChars = TxtBox.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)).GroupBy(x => x);` which sould return a list of groupings with a char as key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would also need to exclude chr(13). 10 = new line, 13 = carriage return.

For each c as char in TxtBox

```
   if c <> chr(10) and c <> chr(13) then
      list.add(c)
   end if
```

Give that a shot.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, both LF = LineFeed = Chr(10) and CR = Carriage Return = Chr(13) are inserted as return character.

This comes from (old) dot-matrix printers.

LineFeed = Move one line down
Carriage Return = Move to the begin of the current line

They are both included in the `Environment.NewLine` property.

So your code should be something like:

```
 If Environment.NewLine.IndexOf(c) < 0 Then
    list.Add(c)
 End If
```

This way your are sure your code also works on OS'es that use different characters for newline.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are already lots of answers, but the way I would have done it is as follows:

```
For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
    List.Add(c)
Next
```

I don't know what your "List" variable is, but if it's of a List type, or of type ListBox.ObjectCollection, or of many other types, you could probably replace this loop with:

```
List.AddRange(TextBox1.Text.Replace(vbCrLf, "").ToCharArray())
```

...just for the fun of it!

Answer (score 1):

Use the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx

```
Char.IsWhiteSpace
```